# ember data serialize embed records

Tags: serialization, ember.js

Ember: 1.5.1 ember.js

Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88

I have a need for asymmetrical (de)serialization for one relationship type: sideloaded records on deserializing and embedded on serializing.

I have asked for this in the standard way:

```
RailsEmberTest.PlanItemSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        completions: {serialize: 'records', deserialize: 'ids'}//embedded: 'always'}
    }
});
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Following the execution through, I find that at line 498 of Ember data, the serializer decides whether or not to embed a relationship:

```
embed = attrs && attrs[key] && attrs[key].embedded === 'always';
```

At this stage, the attrs hash is well-formed, with completions containing the attributes as above. However, this line results in embed being false, and consequently the record is not embedded.

Overriding the value of embed to true makes it all hunky-dory.

Any ideas why Ember data is ignoring the settings? I suspect that maybe in my version the only option is embedded, and I need to upgrade to a later version to take advantage of the asymmetrical settings for serialize and deserialize.

However, given the possible manifold changes I am fearful of upgrading!

I'd be very grateful for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of the London Ember meetup, I now know that it was simply down to the version of Ember Data! Now upgraded to the latest beta with no trouble.